# Add a new Template in Eclipse for Project Type / Executable

Tags: eclipse, templates, types, project, eclipse-cdt

First I'm really new to Eclipse.

I searched a long time for a solution for my problem, and I already found some threads but I can't really follow what they are doing.

So my problem is, I want to add a new "Template" to the New -> C Project -> Project Type - Executable folder in the Wizard.

Like the default "Empty Project" and the "Hello World"
http://s1.directupload.net/images/131027/ktganjqa.png

Somebody know how I can do this?

And it would be nice if you could explain it fully cause, like I'm said, I'm quiet new to Eclipse

Greetz AllesFam

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a plug-in, add a simple definition in the plugin.xml that points to a template.xml where you define what files should be copied to the newly created project.

For simple to average templates, no Java programming is required, the descriptive xml-s are enough.

You can take a look how I added templates to [GNU ARM Eclipse Plug-in](http://gnuarmeclipse.livius.net/blog/), the source code is available from the [SourceForce git](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuarmeclipse/se/ci/master/tree/).